# Can't set margin left userName

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

i have 2 items in a relative layout that i want to put side by side,the User icon and the username, at the moment i have the user icon where i want but the username is always right at the side with no margin, i need some margin left so i can have a litle space between each other, and i tried with margin left but it didn't work.

**here is the xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="142dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_specie_radius">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.NexusBoldTextView
                android:id="@+id/Avaliation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/plantName"
                android:layout_marginStart="92dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dateTxt"
                android:text="Avalie a fotografia" />

            <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.NexusBoldTextView
                android:id="@+id/dateTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/reportImg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/color_cursor_white" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/plantPhoto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/userIcon"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/plantPhoto"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_user"
                />

            <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.NexusBoldTextView
                android:id="@+id/plantName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/plantPhoto"
                android:textColor="@color/nephritis"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.NexusBoldTextView
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/plantPhoto"
                android:textColor="@color/base"
                android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/userIcon"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/userIcon"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: so instead of marginLeft it is margin-right?

Comment: yeah but my question was about my margin left that does't work

Comment: on the username

Comment: you need to set align to horizontal

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Comment: put your layout image for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I have found too issues with your code:

1. You have both `android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/userIcon"` and `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/userIcon"` attributes set in your username view, which makes no sense. You should replace `android:layout_toLeftOf` with `android:layout_toRightOf` if you want it to be to the right of the userIcon view.
2. You are setting the left position of the username view with the `android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/userIcon"` attribute, that's why `android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"` has no effect. You can use `android:paddingLeft="20dp"` instead.

Let me know if it helps.